# Its saying error when I tried using CAST and CASE WHEN together

Tags: sql-server

I'm having problem for Casting CurrRunDate by comparing the values.

```
SELECT
    s.Cid, 
    s.MobileNo, 
    AvailableBalance = (SELECT dbo.GetAvailBalAmt(acc,0)/100 FROM SMSCIF), 
    b.CurrRunDate,
    s.CreatedDate,
    s.ExpiryDate,       
    CAST (CASE WHEN
                  b.CurrRundate < s.ExpiryDate THEN '00' 
                  ELSE '01' 
          END) AS RenewStatus
FROM
    SMSCIF s
LEFT JOIN 
    BRPARMS b ON s.br = b.br
WHERE 
    (CAST(s.CreatedDate AS DATE) = b.CurrRundate AND s.status = '00') 
    OR Cast(s.ExpiryDate As Date) = b.CurrRundate
```

> Error Message : Incorrect syntax near 'Cast', expected 'AS'.

Comment: You're missing the `AS ...` part of the `CAST` expression. It should look like `CAST(expr AS type)`

Comment: Yes, I've fixed that now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `CAST( (CASE expression) AS VARCHAR(2))`, your current query has a syntax error.

Change it to the query below will work:

```
 CAST ((CASE WHEN b.CurrRundate < s.ExpiryDate THEN '00' 
            ELSE '01' END) 
 AS VARCHAR(2)) AS RenewStatus,
```

Comment: That worked thanks to you, but there seems to many other errors now. Ill figure it out i guess. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Assigning an alias to an expression doesn't need `CAST`; remove `CAST`:

```
CASE
    WHEN b.CurrRundate < s.ExpiryDate THEN '00' 
    ELSE '01' 
END AS RenewStatus
```